# Replacing document.write with jQuery for conversion tracking code

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are these tracking scripts that were being used, but they were modified by somebody else a while back because it was causing problems on some pages. The conversion tracking is currently not working, and I don't understand how jQuery is being used to replace the original JavaScript, which are pretty straightforward.

- Note that I could not verify if the fix even ever worked. They're on somebody else's server and account, and I'm unable to get clear information from them.

**Universal tag (appears on all pages) changes:**

From...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ATRK_CLIENT_ID="0000000" ;
    var ATRK_PROTOCOL=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://"); 
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript type='text/javascript' src='" + ATRK_PROTOCOL + "js.acq.io/ATRK_" +
    ATRK_CLIENT_ID + "_min.js' %3E%3C/script%3E" )); 
</script>
```

To...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
        var ATRK_CLIENT_ID="0000000" ;
        var ATRK_PROTOCOL=(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
        jQuery.getScript(ATRK_PROTOCOL + "js.acq.io/ATRK_" + ATRK_CLIENT_ID + "_min.js");
    });
</script>
```

**Conversion code (appears on order success page):**

From...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    ATRKtracker.setTransId('1234567890');
    ...
</script>
```

To...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
        ...
        ATRKtracker.setTransId('1234567890');
        ...
    });
</script>
```

The tracking software is not receiving any tracking information, and I'm not familiar with jQuery or Javascript.

**Questions**

1. In the "fixed" conversion script, is it even necessary to use jQuery? It looks to me you can remain using the original conversion code, regardless of the universal tag modification.
2. The universal tag is really only writing `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.acq.io/ATRK_0000000_min.js"></script>` or `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.acq.io/ATRK_0000000_min.js"></script>` Could you just hardcode and always just use http or https regardless of `document.location.protocol`?

Any ideas?

Comment: Since jQuery is only Javascript, the answer to the question "Do I really need jQuery" is always "no", followed by "but it might just make it easier to make it work cross-browser".

Comment: Are you referring to the conversion script here? If so, I agree. For the universal tag script, I was told `document.write` somehow prevented people from clicking the add-to-cart button, so they modified it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. As @ingo-bürk states the answer is no but the issue you saw is probably because the implementation was wrong. The function wrapped in `jQuery()` was never executed eg. by placing round brackets after it `()`. The `getScript()` change is fine, and the `ATRKtracker.setTransID()` call can stay as it was before.
2. You could hard code it if you can be sure of your protocol but the snippets provided by companies like that are written to work for all kinds of set ups. I'd probably just leave the protocol off all together now though eg. `<script src="//js.acq.io/ATRK_0000000_min.js"></script>` to get the same effect.